# Jquery datatable search text

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatable, controller

How can I catch search text with a parameter in server side. It's always null when I debug the program. I saw this `Request.Form.GetValues("search[value]")[0]` but I want to take it as a parameter. Is it possible ?

```
$('#datatableClients').DataTable({
        "processing": true, 
        "serverSide": true, 
        "filter": true, 
        "orderMulti": false, 
        "ajax": {
            "url": "/Custom/Data/GetRows",
            "type": "POST",
            "datatype": "json"
        },
        "columns": [
                { "data": "FirstName", "name": "First Name", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "LastName", "name": "Last Name", "autoWidth": true }

        ]
    });



public JsonResult GetRows(int draw, int start, int length, string search)
{ 
    // search parameter is null
}
```

Comment: this might help https://github.com/sinhashubh/datatable-examples/tree/master/Sort%20and%20Filter

Comment: You mean as query string?

Comment: yes directly get from search parameter of the method without reading Request.Form